# Is there a way to access the state of a GenServer?

Tags: erlang, elixir, erlang-otp

Is there a built in way to see the current state of a GenServer? You can always implement a simple call to return the state, but is there a more generic way?

When I run :observer.start I can look at the running applications and see their state, so it seems possible. But it may be doing some double-secret Erlang voodoo to get that.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It depends on how you're going to use it.

If obtaining the state is part of your business logic, then yes - this should be properly modelled in your application with `GenServer.call` to return the state.

If you need this only in terms of debugging/insights of your application, you could use [`:sys.get_state`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/sys.html#get_state-1) like this:

```
iex> :sys.get_state(pid)
# some state printed
```

Please be aware of that `:sys.get_state` will accept either `pid` or the name of the server (if it is registered under one).

Also, please take a look at [this section about debugging with `:sys` module](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/GenServer.html#module-debugging-with-the-sys-module) in Elixir's `GenServer` documentation as it is very useful.

Hope that helps!